# Ruby implicit conversion of String into Integer (typeError)

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am trying to use a YAML file, reading from it and writing to it a list of values. On the first run of this script, the yaml file is correctly created, but then on the second it throws a conversion TypeError which I don't know to fix.

```
db_yml = 'store.yml'

require 'psych'
begin
    if File.exist?(db_yml)
        yml = Psych.load_file(db_yml)
        puts "done load"        

        yml['reminders']['reminder_a'] = [123,456] 
        yml['reminders']['reminder_b'] = [457,635,123]
        File.write(db_yml, Psych.dump(yml) ) 
    else 
      #the file does not exist yet, create an empty one.
        File.write(db_yml, Psych.dump(
        {'reminders' => [
            {'reminder_a'=> [nil]}, 
            {'reminder_b'=> [nil]}
        ]}
  )) #Store
    end
rescue IOError => msg  
  # display the system generated error message  
  puts msg 
end
```

produces the file store.yml on first run:

```
---
reminders:
- reminder_a:
  - 
- reminder_b:
  -
```

So far so good. But then on the second run it fails with

```
done load
yamlstore.rb:23:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
        from yamlstore.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

Could you tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the YAML file. However you create the file you create it with the following structure:

```
yaml = {
  'reminders' => [
    {'reminder_a'=> [nil]}, 
    {'reminder_b'=> [nil]}
  ]
}
```

Notice that the contents of `yaml['reminders']` is an array. Where it goes wrong is here:

```
reminders = yaml['reminders']
reminder_a = reminders['reminder_a'] # <= error

# in the question example:
# yml['reminders']['reminder_a'] = [123,456]
```

Since `reminders` is an array you can't access it by passing a string as index. You have 2 options:

1. In my opinion the best option (if you want to access the reminders by key) is changing the structure to use a hash instead of an array:

   ```
   yaml = {
     'reminders' => {
       'reminder_a'=> [nil], 
       'reminder_b'=> [nil]
     }
   }
   ```

   With the above structure you can access your reminder through:

   ```
   yaml['reminders']['reminder_a']
   ```
2. Somewhat clumsy, find the array element with the correct key:

   ```
   yaml['reminders'].each do |reminder|
     reminder['reminder_a'] = [123,456] if reminder.key? 'reminder_a'
     reminder['reminder_b'] = [457,635,123] if reminder.key? 'reminder_b'
   end
   ```

Answer (score 6):

The error message says that you were passing a `String` where Ruby expects something that is implicitly convertible to an `Integer`. The number one place where Ruby expects something that is implicitly convertible to an `Integer` is when indexing into an `Array`. So, whenever you see this error message, you can be 99% sure that you are either indexing an `Array` with something you thought was an `Integer` but isn't, or that you are indexing an `Array` that you thought was something else (most likely a `Hash`). (The other possibility is that you are trying to do arithmetic with a mix of `Integers` and `Strings`.)

Just because Ruby is a dynamically-typed programming language does not mean that you don't need to care about types. In particular, YAML is a (somewhat) typed serialization format.

The type of the file you are creating looks something like this:

```
Map<String, Sequence<Map<String, Sequence<Int | null>>>>
```

However, you are accessing it, as if it were typed like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Sequence<Int | null>>>
```

To put it more concretely, you are creating the value corresponding to the key `'reminders'` as a *sequence* (in YAML terms, an `Array` in Ruby terms) of *maps* (`Hash`es). `Array`s are indexed by `Integers`.

You, however, are indexing it with a `String`, as if it were a `Hash`.

So, you either need to change how you access the values like this:

```
yml['reminders'][0]['reminder_a'] = [123, 456]
#               ↑↑↑

yml['reminders'][1]['reminder_b'] = [457,635,123]
#               ↑↑↑
```

Or change the way you initialize the file like this:

```
File.write(db_yml, Psych.dump(
{ 'reminders' => {
#                ↑
    'reminder_a' => [nil],
#  ↑                     ↑
    'reminder_b' => [nil]
#  ↑                     ↑
}
```

so that the resulting YAML document looks like this:

```
---
reminders:
  reminder_a:
    - 
  reminder_b:
    -
```

Comment: both answers are the same, this one is very nicely laid out, but for brevity sake I went with the other one. Nonetheless, thanks a lot for explaining in detail, much appreciated! +1